# Binomial And Trigonometric Approximations Give Different Answers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, geometry, approximations

So I was solving a question that is based on Simple Harmonic Motion. The question is as follows: There is a spring of spring constant $k$ and natural length $2a$ (it is in its natural length initially). It is then pulled by a very small distance $y$ from the centre perpendicular to its length. We define that the new length is $2\ell$.
[image]
Then from Pythagorean theorem, $\ell = \sqrt{a^2 + y^2}$. Now we know that $y\ll a$, so $\sqrt{a^2 + y^2} = a\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{a^2}}$ and  $\frac{y^2}{a^2}\ll 1,$ so we can use the binomial approximation for $(1+x)^n\approx1+nx$ (if $x\ll 1$). Here n = $\frac{1}{2}$, so we get $\ell = a\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{a^2}}\approx a(1+\frac{y^2}{2a^2}) = a + \frac{y^2}{2a}$.
So extension is final length - original length = $\ell - a \approx \frac{y^2}{2a}$

Now let's consider a different approach. Let us drop a perpendicular from the original centre $O$ to the final configuration of the spring and let the foot of perpendicular be $P$, i.e. :
[image]
Let $\angle COP = \theta$
So now in $\triangle OPB$ we have $OP = OB\sin\theta = a\sin\theta$.
We also have $PB = OB\cos\theta = a\cos\theta = \ell-x$
Now in $\triangle OPC$ we have $PC = OP \tan\theta = a\sin\theta\tan\theta = x$

Since $y\ll a,\ \tan\theta = \frac{y}{a}\approx\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta\approx1$

Now, extension in spring $= \ell-a$ and $\ell = x + \ell-x,$ so $\ell - a = x + \ell-x - a$

extension $= a\sin\theta\tan\theta + a\cos\theta - a \approx a(\frac{y}{a})(\frac{y}{a}) + a - a \approx \frac{y^2}{a}$

This gives a difference of factor of 2 in the extension of the spring, but how is that possible?

Another example is a slight displacement of a pendulum.

[image]

Here in $\triangle CSP,\ \frac{CS}{SP} = \cos\theta$. Thus $CS = SP\cos\theta = \ell\cos\theta$.
so its vertical height rise $= OC = OS - CS = \ell - \ell\cos\theta = \ell(1-\cos\theta),$ but $1-2\sin^2\theta = \cos2\theta$. Thus $1-\cos\theta = 2\sin^2(\frac{θ}{2})$ and as $\theta$ is very small, $\sin\theta\approx\theta$, thus $2\ell\sin^2(\frac{θ}{2}) \approx 2\ell{(\frac{θ}{2})}^2 \approx \ell\frac{θ^2}{2}$

But we can try to get it by another way. $\angle SPO$ is $90^\circ$ because it is $\approx$ tangent at $P$ on the circle with centre $S$ and radius $\ell$. So, the arc $OP \approx$ chord $OP$ because $\theta$ is very small. By definition of radians, we know that the length of arc $OP$ is $\ell\theta$. Next, since $\angle CPO = \theta$, so in $\triangle OPC,\ \frac{OC}{OP} = \tan\theta$. Thus $OC = OP\tan\theta = \ell\theta\tan\theta$. But as $\theta$ is very small, $\tan\theta \approx \theta$. So $OC = \ell\theta\tan\theta \approx \ell\theta^2$.

We again get a difference of factor of 2. What exactly is the problem here and how do I rectify it?

Comment: This might be off-topic as a check-my-work question, I'm not sure.

Comment: Anyway: Main mistake, I think, is ignoring second-order terms in the cosine while expanding up to second order elsewhere. Take into account that $\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$ and things should check out.

Comment: I just added @kricheli's comment into my answer, so that you can see that he is exactly correct, even if he did not deal with the mistake in the pendulum.

Comment: Yeah i understood that, what i tried to say was "@kricheli i saw your comment and tried to understand what you meant and saw @naturallyInconsistent's detailed answer and understood what you meant, thank you for your answer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> extension $=a\sin\theta\tan\theta+a\cos\theta−a\approx a(\frac ya)\frac ya+a−a\approx \frac{y^2}a$

That is simply too rough an approximation, akin to kricheli's comment. Instead, you were so close to having done it properly:
$$\ell-a=a\sin\theta\tan\theta+a\cos\theta-a=a\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta}-1\right)=a\left(\frac1{\cos\theta}-1\right)\approx\frac{y^2}{2a}$$
as required. Of course, you can either choose to do $\frac1{\cos\theta}\approx\frac1{1-\frac{\theta^2}2}\approx1+\frac{\theta^2}2$ or $\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{2\sin^2\frac\theta2}{\cos\theta}\approx2\sin^2\frac\theta2$ (this last approximation because the $\sin^2\frac\theta2$ is already correct to $2^\text{nd}$ order and thus we do not need to expand the cosine in the denominator.

kricheli's comment is that you should have done
$$\ell-a=a\sin\theta\tan\theta+a\cos\theta-a\approx a\theta^2+a(1-\frac{\theta^2}2)-a=a\frac{\theta^2}2\approx \frac{y^2}{2a}$$

---

$\angle SPO\neq90^\circ$ because $SO=OP=\ell$ makes $\triangle SPO$ an isosceles triangle. i.e. $\angle SPO=\perp-\frac\theta2$

This means $\angle CPO=\angle SPO-\angle SPC=(\perp-\frac\theta2)-(\perp-\theta)=\frac\theta2$

This fixes everything. You had a small mistake: in $\triangle OPC,\ OC=OP\sin\angle CPO$ instead of tangent. For how small everything is, chord $OP \approx$ arc $OP,$ and so $OC\approx\ell\theta\frac\theta2=\ell\frac{\theta^2}2$ as required.

---

Good work, just slight mistakes here and there, expected because the manipulations become so long. There are a lot of smart trickery that you can learn, because we have had to deal with these for so many centuries, that we have discovered cheaper methods to get the correct answers.

Comment: Ohk, i get it, thank you so much for this detailed explanation, i understood my entire mistake. This detailed analysis cleared all my conceptual doubts with which i was struggling for the past 2 days, it was much required. Thank you so much once again